# How to find a 2-wise independent hash family that is not 3-wise independent?

Tags: probability-theory, hash

I'm trying to find a family of hash functions mapping $\{1, 2, ..., 2^n\}$ to $\{0, 1\}$ that is 2-wise independent but not 3-wise independent. Any ideas on that?

I know two 2-wise independent families but I think they are 3-wise independent as well:

1) Let x be a vector in $\{0, 1\}^n$. The hash functions are $h_{a, b}(x)=a^\top x+b \mod  2$ for all $a\in\{0, 1\}^n$ and $b\in\{0, 1\}$.

2) Consider $GF(2^n)$. The hash functions are $$h_{a, b}(x)= \text{the last bit of }a \cdot x+b $$ for all $a, b\in GF(2^n)$.

Comment: 1. What families of 2-independent hash functions do you know?  Spend a few hours with a few textbooks and review the standard constructions: I think you'll find that many of the standard constructions meet your requirements.  2. Hint: What happens if you generalize your constructions to a field of characteristic larger than 2?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest example I could find is
$$
0001 \\
0010 \\
0100 \\
1000 \\
0011 \\
0101 \\
0110 \\
1001 \\
1010 \\
1100 \\
1111 \\
1111
$$
I'll leave you to generalize this to larger $n$.

Comment: Could you explain what this means? I don't understand.

Comment: Actually I think I find one. Similar to 1), the functions are $h_a(x)=a^\top x \mod 2$ for all $a\in\{0,1\}^n$, but $\vec0$  is not in the domain now (so the domain is $\{1,2,\cdots,2^n−1\}$).

Comment: I've described a family of 12 hash functions mapping $\{1,2^2\}$ to $\{0,1\}$ which is 2-wise independent but not 3-wise independent (with respect to the uniform measure on the 12 hash functions).